# I don't understand the golang channel well

Tags: go, channel

Goroutines and channels are bothering me these days. I'm looking at the memo5 code at https://github.com/adonovan/gopl.io/tree/master/ch9.
If you look at memo.go of memo5, there are `func (e *entry) call(f Func, key string)` and `func (e *entry) deliver(response chan<- result)` parts.

```
// Copyright © 2016 Alan A. A. Donovan & Brian W. Kernighan.
// License: https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/

// See page 278.

// Package memo provides a concurrency-safe non-blocking memoization
// of a function.  Requests for different keys proceed in parallel.
// Concurrent requests for the same key block until the first completes.
// This implementation uses a monitor goroutine.
package memo

//!+Func

// Func is the type of the function to memoize.
type Func func(key string) (interface{}, error)

// A result is the result of calling a Func.
type result struct {
    value interface{}
    err   error
}

type entry struct {
    res   result
    ready chan struct{} // closed when res is ready
}

//!-Func

//!+get

// A request is a message requesting that the Func be applied to key.
type request struct {
    key      string
    response chan<- result // the client wants a single result
}

type Memo struct{ requests chan request }

// New returns a memoization of f.  Clients must subsequently call Close.
func New(f Func) *Memo {
    memo := &Memo{requests: make(chan request)}
    go memo.server(f)
    return memo
}

func (memo *Memo) Get(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    response := make(chan result)
    memo.requests <- request{key, response}
    res := <-response
    return res.value, res.err
}

func (memo *Memo) Close() { close(memo.requests) }

//!-get

//!+monitor

func (memo *Memo) server(f Func) {
    cache := make(map[string]*entry)
    for req := range memo.requests {
        e := cache[req.key]
        if e == nil {
            // This is the first request for this key.
            e = &entry{ready: make(chan struct{})}
            cache[req.key] = e
            go e.call(f, req.key) // call f(key)
        }
        go e.deliver(req.response)
    }
}

func (e *entry) call(f Func, key string) {
    // Evaluate the function.
    e.res.value, e.res.err = f(key)
    // Broadcast the ready condition.
    close(e.ready)
}

func (e *entry) deliver(response chan<- result) {
    // Wait for the ready condition.
    <-e.ready
    // Send the result to the client.
    response <- e.res
}

//!-monitor
```

I don't understand how  `close(e.ready)` and  `<-e.ready` synchronize here. Even after reading the book, I don't understand. Please tell me what the mechanism is.

Comment: The channel receive operation can always proceed on a closed channel, that means that, in the above example, `<-e.ready` in `deliver` will block until `close(e.ready)` is executed by `call`.

Comment: `close(e.ready)` unblocks `<-e.ready`, because that’s what closing a channel does. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.ready` is more known as `done`  channel. this is a way to tell your ref functions that domething is ready by closing `done` (`e.ready` chan). `<-e.ready` is going to block until its `done` (`closed`).

so... reading this code it means next.

1. `deliver` waits for rediness signal.
2. `call` gets data for e.res `(`e.res.value, e.res.err = f(key)`)
3. `call` releas done channel by closing it (`close(e.ready)`)
4. `deliver` can move throu block reading from `<-e.ready` and send data to `response`

Comment: `<-e.ready` is receive. The channel has not been created, how do I receive it?

Comment: `e = &entry{ready: make(chan struct{})}` check the cache query condition (`e==nil`), its created there.

Comment: It is `close(e.ready)` in the `call()` part. Isn't that closed?

Comment: `close(e.ready)` closes `e.ready` if that's what you asked for. (second close on closed channel will bring panic to your code)

Comment: Execution order is call() -> delivery(). From `call()` to `close(e.ready)` was understood. But I don't understand the `<-e.ready` part of `deliver()` .What does `<-e.ready` mean? Isn't the channel already closed in `call()`?

Comment: A) The is no defined execution order with concurrency. <-E.ready is blocking (nothing written to channel), and unblocks (read default value) once channel is closed.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks!!